# Oracle effect of SELECT FOR UPDATE on other SELECTs

Tags: oracle11g

Just like to know the result in the below scenario.

When we select a record using `FOR UPDATE OF` `table.column_name`.

What would be result set when another simple `SELECT` query runs to fetch the particular record which was locked by `FOR UPDATE OF` ?

Answer (score 1):

There would be no change.  The simple `SELECT` statement would return the appropriate version of the row depending on the session's transaction isolation level and the SCN that it was reading data as of.  The fact that some other session has locked the row has no impact on sessions running simple queries.

Comment: Okay, if that is the case. In a web application if we use FOR UPDATE OF to lock a row and delete it. When some other user in a different session tries to modifying that record which was SELECTED just prior to the delete. this would result in error if I am right ?